# OpenGL in WIndows7

Tags: opengl

I want to write code in OpenGL using Visual Studio 2010 . Now on opening opengl.org , I am redirected to http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html ; which presumes I am using WindowsXP and Visual Studio 6 . The instructions in this page http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut/README-win32.txt dates back to 2001 , and not in current context .

Long story short, is there any tutorial which will help me to program with OpenGL in Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010 .

Thanks in advance for taking the time to answer my question . I am new to this , so please bear with me.

Comment: "Now on opening opengl.org , I am redirected to " Where does OpenGL.org "redirect" you to that site? The [OpenGL Wiki has an extensive Getting Started page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started), including a list of tutorals. Most of which are more current than NeHe, which you should not use.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL development under Window-7 is the very same as it has been for Windows-NT 4, Windows 2k and Windows XP. All the tutorials remain valid.

You **do not** require a OpenGL SDK. Everything you need ships with your compiler. OpenGL is not a library, but an API implemented by the drivers. So make sure you download and install the most recent drivers directly from your GPU's vendor's homepage (don't use the drivers shipping with Windows, because those have only very limited support for OpenGL).

Since you surely want to use recent OpenGL functionality you should however get the [GLEW library](http://glew.sf.net), which eases up the loading process for the so called "extensions" by several orders of magnitude; highly recommended. Then instead of the regular OpenGL header you include `GL/glew.h` and call `glewInit()` right after an OpenGL context has been made active.

Instead of the old, outdated, no longer maintained GLUT, you should use FreeGLUT or OpenGLUT; if using GLUT at all, because you'll hit its limitations very soon. I recommend using GLFW instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, configure your project to link with opengl32.lib etc.:
   [OpenGL config in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871130/opengl-config-in-visual-studio-2010).
2. Look at some NeHe tutorials http://nehe.gamedev.net/.

What about Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7 - I don't think there is some significant differences in API with previous versions of Visual Studio and Windows (at least for simple examples).

Also look at: [OpenGL API Documentation Overview](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/)